# Search a Value in a List and give the information if its true or false, Sheets Script

Tags: google-sheets

What it does is it identifies the status of a line, and if it meets the requirement, it copies and pastes it onto another tab in Google Sheets. However, it repeats the same line if something is changed. What I want is that through a variable 'List' that numbers the items as 1, 2, 3, etc., it identifies if it exists in the second line, and if it does, it doesn't repeat the process.

The goal is to have a general tab in Sheets where all the information is stored, and when a part of the work is completed, it copies the data and inserts it into a separate tab so that the individuals who will continue the work see only what is to be done. Once they finish their work, the information is sent back to the original database and doesn’t remain in the same tab.

However, in the current code, it duplicates the same line several times due to the lack of a verification if the line is already in the new work tab.

It needs to be a programming language that Google Sheets' AppScript understands.

```
function onEdit(e){

var Planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Lista = Planilha.getSheetByName('Lista de Compras');
var Compras = Planilha.getSheetByName('Compras');
var Linha = Lista.getActiveCell().getRow();var Coluna = Lista.getActiveCell().getColumn();

if (Lista.getRange(Linha, 2).getValue() == "Aguardando Cotação" &&
Lista.getRange(Linha, 10).getValue() == "" &&
Lista.getRange(Linha, 15).getValue() == "" ){

              var Dados = Lista.getRange(Linha,1,1,9).getValues();
              var UltimaLinhaCompra = Compras.getLastRow() + 1;
            
              Compras.getRange(UltimaLinhaCompra,1,1,9).setValues(Dados);
              return false

}

else if (Lista.getRange(Linha, 3).getValue() == "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 4).getValue() == "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 5).getValue() == "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 6).getValue() == "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 7).getValue() == "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 8).getValue() == "" ){

            Lista.getRange(Linha, 2).setValue("Incompleto")
            return false  

}
else if (Lista.getRange(Linha, 3).getValue() != "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 4).getValue() != "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 5).getValue() != "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 6).getValue() != "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 7).getValue() != "" ||
Lista.getRange(Linha, 8).getValue() != "" ){

            Lista.getRange(Linha, 2).setValue("Aguardando Cotação") 
            return false

}

}
```